# Find missing numbers in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find each missing number in an array like the following.

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 
  [8] => 9 [9] => 10 [10] => 11 [11] => 12 [12] => 13 [13] => 14 [14] => 15 
  [15] => 16 [16] => 17 [17] => 18 [18] => 19 [19] => 20 [20] => 21 [21] => 22 
  [22] => 23 [23] => 24 [24] => 25 [25] => 26 [26] => 27 [27] => 28 [28] => 29 
  [29] => 30 [30] => 31 [31] => 32 [32] => 33 [33] => 34 [34] => 35 [35] => 36 
  [36] => 37 [37] => 38 [38] => 39 [39] => 40 [40] => 41 [41] => 42 [42] => 43 
  [43] => 44 [44] => 45 [45] => 46 [46] => 47 [47] => 48 [48] => 49 [49] => 50 
  [50] => 51 [51] => 52 [52] => 53 [53] => 54 [54] => 55 [55] => 56 [56] => 57 
  [57] => 58 [58] => 59 [59] => 60 [60] => 61 [61] => 62 [62] => 63 [63] => 64 
  [64] => 67 [65] => 68 [66] => 69 
)
```

The numbers `65`,`66` are missing in this particular array.

My question how do I figure out which numbers are missing with the help of PHP. Specifically what I need to find out is the lowest missing number.

Why: Because then I can assign that number to a member as an id.

Comment: I don't think that's the best way to get a unique id - what happens when you have 100000000 users?  Might take a while to find the id.

Comment: @Jeff Foster, if at any time it takes a long time to find the id, the obvious solution is to `delete users where id > 1000;`. It will be fast again! :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can make use of `array_diff` and `range` functions as:

```
// given array. 3 and 6 are missing.
$arr1 = array(1,2,4,5,7); 

// construct a new array:1,2....max(given array).
$arr2 = range(1,max($arr1));                                                    

// use array_diff to get the missing elements 
$missing = array_diff($arr2,$arr1); // (3,6)
```

Comment: If you have leading zero in the array it does not works

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming the number is the element, not the key, of the array. I'm also assuming that the numbers start from 1, not 0.

```
$Expected = 1;
foreach ($InputArray as $Key => $Number)
{
   if ($Expected != $Number)
   {
       break;
   }
   $Expected++;
}

echo $Number;
```

Comment: I like this because you are not using any function. Good one

Answer (score 5):

For big sorted arrays of unique numbers, you can binary search the array for either the lowest or highest unused number. Cost=Log2N. Example: 65536 items can be searched in 16 loops since

```
if ( arr[hi] - arr[lo] > hi - lo )
  ... there are unused numbers in that range ...
```

So (I don't know PHP, but it can be translated...):

```
lo = first entry index
hi = last entry index
if ( arr[hi] - arr[lo] == hi - lo )
  return arr[hi]+1; // no gaps so return highest + 1
do
  {
  mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
  if ( arr[mid] - arr[lo] > mid - lo )   // there is a gap in the bottom half somewhere
    hi = mid; // search the bottom half
  else
    lo = mid; // search the top half
  } while ( hi > lo + 1 ); // search until 2 left
return arr[lo]+1;
```

Answer (score 5):

If given input is not in sorted order and size of input is very large then we can use following logic in any programming language:

**Algorithm**

1. bring smaller chunk into memory from large input
2. initialize three variables say min = 0, max = 0 and missingIds = []
3. scan smaller chunked input from left to right

   1. if scannedValue found in missingIds 
      then, 
       pop scannedValue from missingIds 
       go to next value;
   2. If scanned value is near to min
      then, 
       find all the missing numbers between scannedValue and min, push into missingIds

      min = scannedValue;
   3. Else if scanned value is near to max
      then, 
       find all the missing numbers between scannedValue and max, push into missingIds

      max = scannedValue;
4. repeat above steps until large input scanned from left to right

**Example in PHP**

```
<?php
$largeInput = [40,41,42,43,44,45,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,35,36,37,38,39,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,67,68,69,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34];
$missingIds = [];
$min = 0;
$max = 0;
$chunkSize = 10;
$chunkNo = 0;
$currentInput = array_slice($largeInput, $chunkNo, $chunkSize);
while(count($currentInput) > 0) {
    foreach($currentInput as $id) {
        if(in_array($id,$missingIds)) {
            $missingIds = array_diff($missingIds,[$id]);
            continue;
        }
        if($id <= $min) {
            $distMin = $min - $id;
            if($distMin > 2) {
                $tempArr = range($id+1,$min-1);
                $missingIds = array_merge($missingIds, $tempArr);
                $tempArr = [];
            } else if ($distMin > 1) {
                $tempArr = [$id+1];
                $missingIds = array_merge($missingIds, $tempArr);
                $tempArr = [];
            } 
            $min = $id;
        } else if ($id >= $max){
            $distMax = $id - $max;
            if($distMax > 2) {
                $tempArr = range($max+1,$id-1);
                $missingIds = array_merge($missingIds, $tempArr);
                $tempArr = [];
            } else if ($distMax > 1) {
                $tempArr = [$max+1];
                $missingIds = array_merge($missingIds, $tempArr);
                $tempArr = [];
            } 
            $max = $id;
        }   
    }
    $chunkNo++;
    $currentInput = array_slice($largeInput, $chunkNo, $chunkSize);
}
print_r($missingIds);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//$idArrayMissing = array([0] => 1, [1] => 2, [2] => 4, [3] => 5, [4] => 6, [5] => 7);
$idArrayMissing = array(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);

//$idArrayFull = array([0] => 1, [1] => 2, [2] => 3, [3] => 4, [4] => 5, [5] => 6);
$idArrayFull = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

function gap($arr)
{
   while (list($k, $v) = each($arr))
      if ($k != ($v-1))
         return $k;
   return -1;
}

print "ok:" . gap($idArrayMissing) . "<br/>\n";
print "full:" . gap($idArrayFull) . "<br/>\n";
```

The return of the gap function can be 2 values:
-1 could indicate that the array has been traversed and there are no free slots or
$k+1 which could indicate that the first free slot is on the end of the array.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using this while idiom instead of foreach($arr as $k => $v)? Also, doesn't this assume that the array is sorted, that the array cursor is zero, and that the values start with 1? And this only gives the first free slot, which is not what the OP asked for exactly.

Comment: The OP did ask for the first free slot! There's no point working out all the values because he's not really interested. You are right with my assumptions. You have missed the fact that my solution won't find gaps at the beginning or end! Besides the example doesn't say that the numbers will be removed or re-inserted, only that the number will be used. list/each is what we used before foreach was added to the language so it's mainly just habit. It should be a lesson to the OP to write questions that *specifically* produce the results he/she wants without too many assumptions on our part.

Comment: it says "each missing number"; maybe it said something different when you posted. I wasn't being critical really, I actually like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done easily by using [in_array() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) like this:

```
// lets say $InputArray has all the data
// lets declare a variable which we will search inside the $InputArray array and lets initialize it with either 0 or 1 or with the minimum value found inside $InputArray

$start_counting = 1;
$max_value = count($InputArray);
  if (!(in_array($start_counting, $InputArray)))
   {
      echo "Value: ".$start_counting." is missing!"."<br>" ;
   }
 else{ 
    if($start_counting <= $max_value -1)    
      {$start_counting++;}
     }
    else  if($start_counting > $max_value -1)
     {
      echo "All missing numbers printed!"
     }  
}
```